# Clarify how cookies are working between Angular and c# controller

Tags: c#, angular, cookies

I would like to clarify how cookies work between angular app and the c# server controller.
This is what I gathered from various discussions and forums:

1. The angular client sends HTTP Request (e.g. to login) to the c# server
2. c# server creates the cookie (e.g. `refreshToken`) using:

   `Response.Cookies.Append("refreshToken", token, cookieOptions);`
3. c# server returns and the cookie `refreshToken` is set in store on the client side
4. Whenever the angular client sends the HTTP request again, the cookie is set in the `Request` object (probably by the browser, behind the scenes - angular client does not explicitly set the cookie)
5. c# server receives the request and retrieves the cookie like below:

   `var refreshToken = Request.Cookies["refreshToken"];`

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the basics of cookies. The browser sets it in each request behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is totally correct.
One note: Angular HttpClient does only include cookies for cross-domain requests (like in dev environment) in the request if HttpOption `withCredentials` is set to true.

Comment: So who is setting the cookie  in the Request object - browser?

Comment: Yes, the browser is setting the cookies, since they are stored in the browser itself. Nevertheless you can configure in angular http client what the browser is allowed to add to the request (and what not).

Comment: So if `var refreshToken = Request.Cookies["refreshToken"];` on the server's side produces null value it's a browser's fault? On the client side I am sending a message like this: `return this.http.post<any>(`${baseUrl}/refresh-token`, {/* headers: headers */}, { withCredentials: true })`

Comment: well, first of all you should take a look at your network tab in your browser and see if the `cookie` header was included in the request headers. If not, we have to move one step back and see where the cookie should be set. Search for this specific request in your network tab and take look at whether the `Set-Cookie` header was present on the response payload. You can also take a look at browser settings to see whether this cookie was stored for your domain.

Comment: When I use Microsoft Edge there is a header `Cookie:` set under the Network tab. But when I use Chrome there is none

Comment: Did you perform the request where the cookie should be set in the first place also in Chrome? Of course a cookie can be only send by the browser when it was first stored in the browser.

Comment: It was my fault . Its all working fine now. Do you want me to explain?

Comment: Sure, go ahead! What was the issue?

Comment: I was running debug angular on the wrong ip address (localhost) instead of real ip address 192.168.0.17